# Not able to apply the most simple screw modifier possible

Tags: screw-modifier

1. Add curve
2. Rotate as displayed in picture below
3. Add screw modifier

Tried other axis, got a dome instead of a ring

I want the result on the left but got the one on the right instead.

[image: pic]

https://youtu.be/gbNo0odrSVg?t=31

Comment: CTRL A > Rotation

Answer (score 0):

The axis of the screw modifier is set to Y in the first example, but it’s set to Z in the second example. Change this, and everything should be fine.